# How to prevent zoom after selecting element in layer on iOS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to fix a strange behaviour on my project only occuring on iOS devices. There is a popup window with list elements, where on selecting an item it will close the layer and change another label.

After selectign the element, the page zooms in which looks realy odd and should not occure. As this is really difficult to isolate into an minimal example I am including the [link to the probject](https://watchgurus.de). If you click on "Marke auswählen" and you select a brand, you will see the problem on an iOS device.

How can this zoom be disabled? The font size is 16px and should therefore be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the `<head>`

[Responsive Meta tag Article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: I have already this  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">, is this not the same one?